# Why iOS AudioQueue memory constantly increasing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audioqueue

I hava a Play audio class used `AudioToolBox.framework` ,`AudioQueue`.

I encountered a problem, every piece of audio data playback, the memory will be increased, after playback is complete, the memory will not be reduced. If the batch test, it will be added to the hundreds of megabytes of memory, I want to know what causes memory has been increased, the audio data on each pass of each object is released or other reasons.

Here is my playThread class code:

```
@interface PlayThread()
{
    BOOL transferDataComplete; // if thers is no data transfer to   playthread set transferDataComplete = yes;
    NSMutableArray *receiveDataArray;// audio data array
    BOOL isPlay;// if audioqueue start,isPlay = yes,
}
@end
#pragma mark class implementation
@implementation PlayThread
- (instancetype)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        receiveDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        isPlay = NO;
        transferDataComplete = false;
        bufferOverCount = QUEUE_BUFFER_SIZE;
        audioQueue = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

// audio queue callback function
static void BufferCallback(void *inUserData,AudioQueueRef    inAQ,AudioQueueBufferRef buffer)
{
    USCPlayThread* player=(__bridge USCPlayThread*)inUserData;
    [player fillBuffer:inAQ queueBuffer:buffer];
}
// fill buffer
-(void)fillBuffer:(AudioQueueRef)queue queueBuffer:(AudioQueueBufferRef)buffer
{
    while (true){
        NSData *audioData = [self getAudioData];
        if( transferDataComplete && audioData == nil) {
           bufferOverCount --;
           break;
        }
        else if(audioData != nil){
            memcpy(buffer->mAudioData, [audioData bytes] , audioData.length);
                buffer->mAudioDataByteSize = (UInt32)audioData.length;
                AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(queue, buffer, 0, NULL);
                break;
            }
            else
                break;
        } // while
        if(bufferOverCount == 0){
            // stop audioqueue
            [self stopAudioQueue];
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(playComplete)])     {
                    [self.delegate playComplete];
                }
            });
        }
    }

-(void)addPlayData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSUInteger count = 0;
     @synchronized(receiveDataArray){
        [receiveDataArray addObject:data];
    }
 }
 /**
 *  get data from receiveDataArray
 */
-(NSData*)getAudioData
{
    NSData *headData = nil;
    @synchronized(receiveDataArray){
        if(receiveDataArray.count > 0){
            headData = [receiveDataArray objectAtIndex:0];
            [receiveDataArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }
    return headData;
}

- (void)startPlay // start audioqueue to play audio data
{
    [self reset];
    [self open];
    for(int i=0; i<QUEUE_BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
    {
        [self fillBuffer:audioQueue queueBuffer:audioQueueBuffers[i]];
    }
    // audioqueuestart
    AudioQueueStart(audioQueue, NULL);

    @synchronized(self){
        isPlay = YES;
    }
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(playBegin)]) {
        [self.delegate playBegin];
    }
}
-(void)createAudioQueue
{
    if (audioQueue) {
        return;
    }
    AudioQueueNewOutput(&audioDescription, BufferCallback, (__bridge void *)(self), nil, nil, 0, &audioQueue);
    if(audioQueue){
        for(int i=0;i<QUEUE_BUFFER_SIZE;i++){
            AudioQueueAllocateBufferWithPacketDescriptions(audioQueue, EVERY_READ_LENGTH, 0, &audioQueueBuffers[i]);
        }
    }
}
-(void)stopAudioQueue
{
    if(audioQueue == nil){
        return;
    }
    @synchronized(self){
        if(isPlay){
            isPlay = NO;
        }
    }
    AudioQueueStop(audioQueue, TRUE);
}
-(void)setAudioFormat
{
    audioDescription.mSampleRate = 16000;
    audioDescription.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioDescription.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    audioDescription.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    audioDescription.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    audioDescription.mBytesPerFrame = (audioDescription.mBitsPerChannel/8) *      audioDescription.mChannelsPerFrame;
    audioDescription.mBytesPerPacket = audioDescription.mBytesPerFrame ;
  }

  -(void)close
    {
       if (audioQueue) {
        AudioQueueStop(audioQueue, true);
        AudioQueueDispose(audioQueue, true);
        audioQueue = nil;
        isPlay = NO;
    }
}

-(BOOL)open {
    if([self isOpen]){
        return YES;
    }
    [self close];
    [self setAudioFormat];
    [self createAudioQueue];
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)isOpen
{
    return (audioQueue != nil);
}

- (void)reset
{
    bufferOverCount = QUEUE_BUFFER_SIZE;
    transferDataComplete = NO;
}

- (BOOL)isPlaying
{
    return isPlay;
}

- (void)disposeQueue
{
    if (audioQueue) {
        AudioQueueDispose(audioQueue, YES);
    }
    audioQueue = nil;
}
 - (void)dealloc
{
    [self disposeQueue];
}
```

Here is ViewContrller.m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

PlayThread *playThread = [[PlayThread alloc]init];
playThread.delegate = self;
self.playThread = playThread;

for (int  i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{   // create empth audio data to simulate
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithLength:10000];
    [self.playThread addPlayData:data];
}
    [self.playThread startPlay]; 
}
```

Here is PlayThread's delegate method:

```
// When the play completely,then play once again,memory will continue to increase
- (void)playComplete
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        for (int  i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithLength:10000];
            [self.playThread addPlayData:data];
        }
        [self.playThread startPlay];
    });
}
```

`Why memory has continued to increase, how can promptly release memory?`

Comment: The best way to see this is to run the Instruments on memory monitor.

Comment: Couple questions and I'll see if I can't look in to this later, but 1) is this using ARC and 2) does PlayThread subclass anything other than NSObject?

Comment: is using ARC and PlayThread is subclass of NSObject.

Comment: Had a same issue. I solved it by passing CFRunLoopGetCurrent() to inCallbackRunLoop on AudioQueueNewOutput method

Answer (score 0):

AudioQueueNewOutput(&audioDescription, BufferCallback, (__bridge void *)(self), nil, nil, 0, &audioQueue);
here parameter can not be nil